# create custom SRID from OGCWKT

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

I wanted to create a new SRID for use in PostGIS. My goal is to have a SRS that can cover an entire state (instead of have multiple zones as in SPCS). For example, I wanted to create a new SRS for Kansas, based on a compromise between

Kansas North (EPSG 3427):

> PROJCS["NAD83(HARN) / Kansas North (ft
>   US)",GEOGCS["NAD83(HARN)",DATUM["NAD83_High_Accuracy_Regional_Network",SPHEROID["GRS
>   1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6152"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4152"]],UNIT["US
>   survey
>   foot",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",39.78333333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",38.71666666666667],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",38.33333333333334],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-98],PARAMETER["false_easting",1312333.3333],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3427"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]

Kansas South (EPSG 3428):

> PROJCS["NAD83(HARN) / Kansas South (ft
>   US)",GEOGCS["NAD83(HARN)",DATUM["NAD83_High_Accuracy_Regional_Network",SPHEROID["GRS
>   1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6152"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4152"]],UNIT["US
>   survey
>   foot",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",38.56666666666667],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",37.26666666666667],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",36.66666666666666],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-98.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",1312333.3333],PARAMETER["false_northing",1312333.3333],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3428"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]]

I wanted to combine these into one coordinate reference system. My questions are:

How can I create a new SRS based on OGCWKT?
(There's a related question [Create custom coordinate system in postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239807), but it turns out that the OP is just wasn't able to find an existing SRID, and the answer is about finding and inserting an existing SRID into PostGIS).

My plan is to use `standard_parallel_1` from the North Zone, and `standard_parallel_2` from the South Zone to create the new SRS.

Can I just make a copy of the North Zone, and change the two standard parallels to get the new OGCWKT, or are there additional parameters I must change?

I have basic knowledge about projections in general, but not a lot.

Comment: Why don't you use NAD83 / Kansas LCC EPSG:6922 or the ft-US EPSG:6923? It should be valid for the whole state.

Comment: @AndreJ Your are right. I'm using it right now after I finding it in further search. I was searching in spatialreference.org with Kansas and didn't find anything in my first attempt. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: And again nobody gave any response to original question - how to "create custom SRID from OGCWKT" :/