# How safe is it to delete rows from spatial_ref_sys

Tags: postgis

How safe is it to delete rows from the **spatial_ref_sys** table of PostGIS ?

Obviously, I would not remove the rows describing CRS I may have to use, but could it still have side effects?

Comment: fine, if you make a backup first, right? we did and added to the table custom projections. related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239807/creating-custom-coordinate-system-in-postgis?rq=1

Comment: what would be the purpose of deleting these rows?

Comment: The purpose is to decrease the number of rows stored in my database as it is used in a platform as a service which restricts the total number of rows in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in PostGIS official documentation https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ch04.html#spatial_ref_sys, this information is needed to transform/reproject between spatial reference systems. So if you don't use those SRS you can delete them or create your own (always backup).